# How do I show that this function is not bijective?

Tags: calculus

My question is sample: I want to show that there is no open $V \subset \mathbb{R}$ around $x=0$ such the function:

$$f(x)= x^2sin(1/x), \mbox{   }x\in V-\ \{0\}$$ 
$$f(0)=0$$

is bijective. 
I just want a hint.

Comment: Show that $f$ is $0$ on more than one input.

Comment: Remark: You need to specify the codomain if you want to prove that a function is bijective. However in this ecample it is sufficient to show that the function is not injective.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $f(\frac{1}{n \pi})=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N.$ Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
A bijective function is a which is both one-one and onto function.
Now you can prove that the function is not bijective by proving that the function is not one-one or the function is not onto. 
It would be much easier to prove that the function is one-one.The various methods to check injectivity of a function are:
1) For a one one function it gives same output for same number or for one input it gives only one output this can be exploited by proving either one of the following:
  $$ if x_1 =x_2, then f(x_1) \ne f(x_2) $$
  $$ if x_1 \ne x_2, then f(x_1) = f(x_2) $$
2)you can check the function's slope(Slope can be found out by finding the derivative of the function or simply differentiating it once)-If the slope is independent of x hence the function is either increasing or decreasing so it is one-one else not.